# does google-text-to-speech filter profanity?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

When my text/ssml contains some word, such as "sex", "drug", "condom", the voice I receive will be wrong, "sex" will be read as three letters, "s", "e", "x", "condom" as five letters, and "drug" as "Dr.","g", wrong more.

Here is some of texts with problems:

"I told her about abstinence, **cоndоm**, everything."

"Did you mention oral **sеx** as a work-around?"

"what with all my drinking and **drսg** and dealing and managing an international escort service with ties to the Russian mob"

And my request code was doing right, because the voice I get is no problem without those profanity in my text/ssml.

here is my codes:

```js
const textToSpeech = require("@google-cloud/text-to-speech").v1beta1;
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
async function speech(text, name) {
  var error = await ssmlCheck.check(text);
  const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
  var request = {
    input: {
      ssml: text,
    },
    voice: {
      languageCode: "en-US",
      name: "en-US-Wavenet-E",
      ssmlGender: "FEMALE",
    },
    audioConfig: {
      audioEncoding: "MP3",
    },
    enableTimePointing: ["SSML_MARK"],
  };
  const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
  const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
  await writeFile(name + ".mp3", response.audioContent, "binary");
  await writeFile(name + ".json", JSON.stringify(response.timepoints));
}
```

Comment: I think you have answered your own question then?

Comment: thanks! Text-to-Speech documentation does not have any info on profanity, not tell how to solve the problem,  but Speech-to-Text does.

Comment: Intriguing; please do post an answer with more details?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved. i finally figured out that unlike Speech-to-Text, google's Text-to-Speech has no profanity filter at all, the source of the text I used is the reason. the following pic is saying everything.

[image]